# Java, time-related objects and oracle to_date function

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, to-date

I have an Oracle database with column called `UPDATED` marked in sqlDeveloper as     `TIMESTAMP(6)`. An example entry in that column is `05-MAY-18 04.49.45.000000000`

I want to execute following query against it using prepared statement:

`SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WHERE UPDATED > TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`.

The question is - how do I bind Java date timeobject (from `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` or `java.time.LocalDateTime` or any other that keeps both data and time?

Here is a test snippet, no matter what I do I can't make it work (apart from situation where I bind `new Date(2018, 5,5)` but firstly it is just date without time and secondly `sql.Date` is outdated.

```
public class Dbaccess {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("someurl", "some_username", "some_password");
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE UPDATED > TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')");
        preparedStatement.setObject(1, LocalDateTime.now());
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("resultSet:" + resultSet);
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("some_id"));
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type`.

How should we these days binds such variable that is supposed to represent datetime?

Comment: important - it works if I deploy it on h2 database with Oracle compatibility mode but fails on normal oracle db, so it needs to be replicated on real oracle db

Comment: The parameter you're sending should be a `String`. Why are you doing that, when you can send it as a `java.sql.Timestamp` instead?

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure what you mean - could you please elaborate?

Comment: First, your query here tries to receive a `String`: `WHERE UPDATED > TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`. This is plain wrong. You can pass an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp` instead that is already a datetime object for Oracle database. So, your query would be changed to `WHERE UPDATED > ?`.

Comment: Ah, I see, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `setDate` like this :

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
//Convert LocalDateTime to SQL TimeStamp
java.sql.Timestamp dateTimeSql = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
//Set this time stamp to the query
preparedStatement.setDate(1, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(dateTimeSql));
```

Or just :

```
preparedStatement.setDate(1, 
     java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()))
);
```

then you don't need to use `TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` you can just use :

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE UPDATED > ?
```

Comment: I retracted my comment. I failed to notice the column type in play was `TIMESTAMP`, without time zone.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Check what **version of JDBC** is supported by your JDBC driver.

In JDBC 4.2 and later, you can do the following:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(
    … ,
    LocalDateTime.now()
)
```

Before JDBC 4.2, see [Answer by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50217225/642706).

## JDBC 4.2

As of [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database. No need to ever use `java.sql.Timestamp` again.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now() ;  // Better to pass explicitly your desired time zone rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default.
```

Pass to your prepared statement with `setObject` method.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

## JDBC 4.1 and earlier

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is not yet updated for JDBC 4.2 or later, see [the Answer by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50217225/642706).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).